# Lambda function python script using psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, lambda, aws-lambda

[Full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb31Y.png)

[Runtime settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muzrP.png)

I am going to connect RDS postgresql Database using Lambda function (python script)
I attached screenhot.
The error logs here.
`Unable to import module 'postgres_test': No module named 'psycopg2'`

python version is 3.6

This issue causing due to not installed psycopg2 package.
Then I don't know how can I install the package on lambda
Pls guide me for it.

postgres_test.py:

`

```
import sys
import logging
import psycopg2

from db_util import make_conn, fetch_data
def lambda_handler(event, context):
query_cmd = "select count(*) from tablename"
# print query_cmd

# get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
conn = make_conn()

result = fetch_data(conn, query_cmd)
conn.close()

return result
```

db_util.py:

`    ​

```
   ​import psycopg2

   ​db_host = "db_host" 
   ​db_port = 5432
   ​db_name = "db_name "
   ​db_user = "db_user "
   ​db_pass = "db_pass "
   ​db_table = "users"


   ​def make_conn():
       ​conn = None
       ​try:
           ​conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='%s' user='%s' host='%s' 
   ​password='%s'" % (db_name, db_user, db_host, db_pass))
       ​except:
           ​print "I am unable to connect to the database"
       ​return conn


   ​def fetch_data(conn, query):
       ​result = []
       ​print "Now executing: %s" % (query)
       ​cursor = conn.cursor()
       ​cursor.execute(query)

       ​raw = cursor.fetchall()
       ​for line in raw:
           ​result.append(line)

       ​return result
```

Comment: please include the relevant code in the body of your question as text so it can be searched and copy and pasted to help us help you!

Comment: Are you sure psycopg2 is installed?

Comment: No, it isn't installed on lambda. I don't know how can I install psycopg2 on lambda. @kubatucka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with different libraries in lambda you have to install the library in the current project and upload it as zip file to lambda.

Specific to psycopg2 use this repo
https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2

And to install some other library use the below command

 For example `requests` library

```
pip install requests -t .
```

Your project will look something like below

```
.
├── lambda_function.py
├── psycopg2
├── <library2>
```

To upload a project to lambda using zip file method you can use the following links

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html
https://alexharv074.github.io/2018/08/18/creating-a-zip-file-for-an-aws-lambda-python-function.html

Comment: Do I need to upload venv folder together? @Anand

Comment: nope in lambda venv folder doesnt really makes sense in the current project root level just install all the libraries

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: I am not sure what `psycopg2` means from the project structure.  I will be great if you provide me sample zip file for it.

Comment: I have added a git repo in the answer specific to psycopg2 repo. can you check the readme of it and clone specific folder in your repo - https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2

Comment: If using python-3.6 then just copy  psycopg2-3.6 from the repo and rename it to psycopg2

Comment: Thank you.  the issue fixed once followed as you mentioned.  I posted new issue continuous from here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638493/aws-lambda-function-python-script-task-timed-out-error    can you reply on there?